How can I enable comments for posts made prior to adding a discussion group to the channel?
I have a channel with published posts that has no associated discussion group.
I now want to turn on commenting for posts in this channel, including those already published, but associating a channel with a discussion group only enables commenting for new posts.
I could republish the existing posts, but then I would lose the original metadata such as  original publication date, and statistics like views, likes etc.
Is there a way to enable comments for the existing posts  without republishing them or  should I be making a Telegram feature request?
This related thread on Reddit, "How to enable comments for specific posts in channel?",
shows that comments for specific posts in a channel can be turned off (actually disabled forever) by removing the posts from the discussion group, but doesn't address how to do the reverse.

Per the Telegram API (API > Discussion groups), what is taking place   under the covers after linking a channel with a discussion group is that a copy of all new posts to the channel is  forwarded to the discussion group, and the comments are the linked discussion thread.
That may be the issue with "adding" commenting to older posts.

The comment section of a channel post is simply the message thread of
the automatically forwarded channel message in the linked discussion
supergroup. 
Thus, the comment section of a particular post can be
disabled by removing the autoforwarded channel post message from the
discussion group.

I suspect what you want to do isn't possible using the current API because of how they've implemented the functionality.
Based on API notes in the Discussion groups section as well as in Channels, supergroups, gigagroups and basic… there are several separate elements synchronizing changes.
Comments are not in the channel but sync'ed from a seperate unique message in a discussion group.
Users can also comment in the channel which then posts that comment to the discussion group which syncs them back to the channel.
The implementation choices for the discussion groups may  reflect the addition of new features to a system architecture that wasn't originally designed with this  functionality in mind.
Given the way they chose to (needed to?) implement discussion groups, I imagine grandfathering existing channel posts when setting up a group is not trivial to implement which makes it unlikely they'll be very  motivated to accommodate your request for new functionality.

This appears to be design flaw. Probably it will be possible to fix by manual forwarding not existing or deleted posts to discussion group again and press some new button there that will make such association again with ability to add comments. Forwarded posts will be placed in the end of the list with other posts (not in the same place where original post is placed in the channel). But I think this must not be a problem. Also may be it will be possible to add such posts back in the middle of other posts . This depends on the design of posts ordering in the group (I do not know the details).

@AntonSamokat I added my comments as edits to the answer.

It seems that now it is not possible without reposting the old posts and deleting them. I've created corresponding feature request for Telegram:
How to enable comments for old previous posts in channel that were published before association the channel with corresponding comments group
If you interested in this feature please mark it with thumb up there.
